# Compiling wxWidgets Project in Virtual Machine (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, codeblocks, wxwidgets

This is a strange one because I didn't have this issue with Ubuntu outside a Virtual Machine. So I am running Virtual Box on OSX. I have Ubuntu 16 loaded and I have wxWidgets installed and compiled. The samples compile just fine and run just fine from the Virtual Box so I know wxWidgets is running fine.

I have Code::Blocks running in my Virtual Machine for Ubuntu and I am building a very simple, if not default program in Code::Blocks. I am just creating a new project and running the project from the default code given. When I compile the project these are the errors I am getting.

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|23|error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|25|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|34|error: ‘wxStaticText’ does not name a type|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|35|error: ‘wxButton’ does not name a type|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|36|error: ‘wxStaticLine’ does not name a type|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|37|error: ‘wxButton’ does not name a type|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testApp.cpp||In member function ‘virtual bool testApp::OnInit()’:|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testApp.cpp|26|error: no matching function for call to ‘testDialog::testDialog(long int, const wxString&)’|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|22|note: candidate: testDialog::testDialog()|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|22|note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|22|note: candidate: testDialog::testDialog(const testDialog&)|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testMain.h|22|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided|
/home/brdavid/Documents/test/testApp.cpp|28|error: ‘class testDialog’ has no member named ‘Show’|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I thought perhaps the global variables haven't been set, which was the case. So I added the base, include, and lib as /home/wxWidgets-3.0.2, /home/wxWidgets-3.0.2/include, /home/wxWidgets-3.0.2/lib respectively.

That didn't resolve the issue. I have placed my wx-config --cflags and wx-config --libs in the correct places to build this program.

Still this does not resolve the issue. I have never seen this before and my first guess is my global variables are not pointing to the right spot. But that is the correct path unless I need to add something to precede it.

any ideas?

Update to include information asked.

I configured the library using the wiki page. ../configure --disable-shared --enable-unicode --enable-release.

-cflags:
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-static-3.0 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D D__WXGTK__ -thread

libs:
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_net-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.a -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lSM -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpng -lexpat -lwxregexu-3.0 -lwxtiff-3.0 -lwxjpeg-3.0 -lz -ldl -lm

Comment: what's the output of wx-config --cxxflags and wx-config --libs? Maybe you have a second wxWidgets install somewhere and wx-config is confused?

Comment: I checked these outputs. They check out to me. I don't believe I have a second install anywhere either. However does it matter what you call the build directories when you build the debug version and release version? I created the directories as such "gtk-build-debug". I doubt that has anything to do with it but I guess right now I'm looking for anything.

Comment: Where do yo have wx compiled libs? In Linux normally you don't build them at `home/wxWidgets-3.0.2/lib`

Comment: @DaveK, how did you configure the library? Can you copy&paste the full configure line you used? And then post the output of wx-config --cxxflags and wx-config --libs.

Comment: I configured the library using the wiki page. ../configure --disable-shared --enable-unicode --enable-release.

Comment: ripi2: You might be right. I just did a pwd on my wxWidgets directory and I forgot to add my username. That might be it. Let me try that here and I will update.

Comment: I tried updating the path and still no go.

Comment: @DaveK, can you compile and run 'minimal' sample that comes with wxWidgets?

Comment: Yep! I have compiled everything under samples and everything there runs fine.

Comment: Update: This is definitely a virtual box issue. I had a back up laptop I decided to make into a Ubuntu box, compiled wxWidgets, installed code::blocks and everything worked out of the box. It is possible that code::blocks doesn't play well with a Virtual system.